# How uber-go/zap logger logs to a Kafka topic?

Tags: go, logging, kafka-topic

Can I get an example to publish the logs to kafka topic. I am currently using uber-go/zap logger and using https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go to publish.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this project, which provides a log sink for Kafka: https://github.com/jeffzhangme/zapx.

It should be easy to adapt this to use `confluent-kafka-go` and any other changes as per your requirement looking at the source code for this project.